# What is the core function for a spring animation (in JavaScript) which takes a currentTime or currentFrame as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, spring, physics

I can't use react-spring because I want to do something lower level, and couldn't find their core spring code [anywhere](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/blob/70efa0d527d9224c474c8ed1bc61fe6c59e162a9/packages/core/src/hooks/useSprings.ts). I have searched around for a standalone simple spring library on npmjs.org but haven't found anything (surprisingly!). I saw [this Vue.js spring code](https://github.com/ismail9k/vue3-spring/blob/1b51ce92ee559567b8ef46bbdd458f8c1f792113/src/lib/core.ts), which seems close:

```
function dumpValue() {
  const { stiffness, damping, mass } = props;

  // check if value is already dumped
  if (isDumped()) {
    // If dumped start animation in reverse direction
    if (props.isPendulum) {
      switchValueDirection();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  const springForce = -1 * stiffness * (state.currentValue - state.desiredValue);
  const damperForce = -1 * damping * state.velocity;
  const acceleration = (springForce + damperForce) / mass;

  state.velocity += acceleration / props.framesPerSecond;
  state.currentValue += state.velocity / props.framesPerSecond;
  cancelAnimation(animationId);
  animationId = requestAnimation(dumpValue);
}
```

So my question is, what is a standalone spring calculation function that takes as input the `currentTime`, `currentFrame`, or something along those lines (plus any other required inputs)? I would like to have a function where I can render a single slice of the spring animation at a certain point, so in theory you could build an "animation editor" UI and rewind/fastforward or drag a slider to move through the spring animation. So the function should take some sort of time/frame input. The concept of physics and getting this right is a bit over my head, so hoping for something simple and standard, like your standard [`easing` functions](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/blob/70efa0d527d9224c474c8ed1bc61fe6c59e162a9/packages/shared/src/easings.ts#L83-L151) (which take a timestamp).

Comment: Do you have to do it by calculating a percent til completion instead? https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/blob/9e3ce95bacaa9a1b259f969870a21c727232cc68/src/stepper.js If so that is fine too.

Comment: Here we go https://github.com/remotion-dev/remotion/blob/fe65830efb80f2280bacfe873bf35edf56a9783c/packages/core/src/spring/index.ts#L5 I guess I can hack around with that, but it would be nice to summarize this in an answer somehow.